Ubuntu 24.04 sound volume issues for Huawei matebook HUAWEI MRGFG-XX
The sound works, but when lowering the volume the sound goes very strange as if coming from only a few speakers. As a workaround I can use alsamixer to keep the speaker volume on 100 and lower master volume instead, which produces much better results.
Ubuntu panel sound:

Alsamixer opens with:

I can then use F6 which gives the - (default) and default:0 soft-hda-dsp. Selecting the soft-hda-dsp allows me to change master volume while keeping the speaker volume at 100 
If I could get help with any of the following questions I'd be grateful:

Would it be possible to bind the ubuntu sound control to master, so I would not have open the alsamixer to change volume?
Is it possible to remove the - default option from alsamixer, as it does not seem to be very useful?
Or is there any better solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.
